# Metaio ARViewController with Image View on top in xcode

Tags: xcode, plugins, imageview, cloud, metaio

The Metaio Cloud plugin lets me setup an xcode 5 project (tabbed, two tabs) and set one of the view controllers to have custom class "ARViewController". This makes that view controller utilize the cloud plugin and show the view of the iphones camera for augmented reality.

I would like to overlay my logo onto this custom view controller, so I dragged an image view to the view controller, set the image source, and set the view mode to top. I set the background and tint to clear color, but for some reason I no longer see the camera view - I only see black.

Is there a reason this would either:

1) Make the ARViewController not work? or

2) make the image view black everywhere besides the logo, covering the ARViewController so that it can not be seen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue. I put the ARViewController in a "container view" so the order of my items in storyboard is like this:

```
View
-Container View (Attach ARViewController to this view)
-Image View (Position on top of container view by clicking
   "Editor">"Arrange">"Send to Front")
```